# Can't find how to define if id exist in $(this)

Tags: jquery, input, this, undefined, attr

In many fieldset, with a next button i try to find if there is "#required" id input, and then, if it's empty, return false (stay in this fieldset) else go on actions ...

```
if ($(this).attr('required').length == 0) {
    alert ('oui');
    if (!$(this).attr('required')) 
        return false;
}
else 
    alert ('non');
```

But `$(this).attr('required').length` is `undefined` because no `id` found.

need help, thanks for all.

I explain : in fieldset (dynamicaly created) if an input with id #required exist, i have to check if it's empty. If it is, click on button will return false.
I'm French and new to jQuery so sorry for everything =\

### The HTML :

```
[...]
   <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Accueil Particulier</h2>
      <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Nombre de personnes :</h3>
      <input type="number" class="required" name="par_venu_f" placeholder="Femme(s)"/>
      <input type="number" class="required" name="par_venu_h" placeholder="Homme(s)"/>
      <br/><br/><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent"/>
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Suivant"/>
   </fieldset>
[...]
```

### EDIT :

Ok, now i'm here :

```
  if ($(this).parent().children().hasClass('required')) {
    if ($(this).parent().children('.required').val().length == 0) {
      alert('find, empty')
      return false;
    };
    alert ('find, full');
  }
  else alert ('not find');
```

It's Ok but when it's check only the first input[type=text], how can i check the others ?

EDIT 2 :
I try .each() function but don't understand how it's work ...

### ANSWER :

Great thanks to @TrueBlueAussie even if i find this alone a few minute ago :

```
  //check if class="required" exist
  if ($(this).parent().children().hasClass('required')) {
    //start of each class="required"
    $(this).parent().children('.required').each(function() {
      //if empty, do not continue
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {fill_required = false;};
    //end each
    });
  // end if exist
  };

  // if there is one empty field, will be false so ...
  if (!fill_required) {
    // make it true before leave then ...
    fill_required = true;
    // leave.
    return false;
  //end if one empty
  };
```

Comment: Can you post HTML ? Use `.attr('id')` instead `.attr('required')`

Comment: Your question is not clear. You mention looking for an element with `id` of 'required', yet your code is looking for an attribute? It may help if you post your HTML and more of your jQuery code so we can see what `this` is referring to

Comment: You have to define an element before using $(this)  
`if ($('#myId').attr('required').length == 0)` then use it on the next coming line

Comment: `$(this).attr('required').length` ..makes no sense

Comment: "But $(this).attr('required').length it's undifined because no id found "  What???

Comment: @bipen unless he wants to get the length of `required` attributes' value.... yeah it makes no sense :)

Comment: does     $(this).attr('id') === 'required'  make more sense ?

Comment: +1: Given English is not your first language, but you did provide code and HTML, I think a little support for your first post is in order :) Welcome to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never have duplicate id's on a page. Use a `class` or `data-...` attribute instead for your "required" flags as their will often be more than one.

You also need to check for the existence of the flag (not its length), then check the input for a value (e.g. with `val()`). It also looks like you are mixing up your "required" test with your "input field value is blank" test.

if you use an attribute (like `data-required=""`) your code would look something like:

```
if ($(this).data('required') && $(this).val().length == 0) {
    alert ('oui');
    return false;
}
else 
    alert ('non');
```

If you use a class it will look something like:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('required') && $(this).val().length == 0) {
    alert ('oui');
    return false;
}
else 
    alert ('non');
```

I would personally recommend using a class for required in this case as it also means that you can style required fields a little different (different colored border around input etc).

*You probably want to trim your values before length check as well so that blank(spaces) are ignored*

### Update - based on changes to question:

If you want to check all "required" fields, you need to loop like this:

```
   // Default is "OK to submit"
   var allow = true;

   // test each required field for a value
   $('.required').each(function(){
       $input = $(this);

       // If we don't have a value, abort with "NOT OK to submit"
       if ($input.val().length == 0){
            allow = false;
            return false;   // <<< this just aborts the each() call
       }
   }
   if (allow){
       alert ('non');
   }
   else {
       alert ('oui');
       return false;
   }
```

The can be simplified/shortened but I wanted it to be clear what it does.

Comment: ok it's seems to ok (about the way of thinking) but how can i catch `input.required` which is  before the button ... and sometimes there two field so how can i check both ?
your code doesn't work, but help me to understood how it work. thx :
`if ($(this).hasClass('required') && (this).parent().find('.required').val().length == 0) {` this doesn't work too ... no idea ?
and thanks to @TrueBlueAussie =D

Comment: I did not expect the code to work *as-is* as too many changes were needed (it was just an example). I have updated the answer based on your updated question.